# R: Displaying a Legend using ggplot2 with multiple dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using ggplot to plot multiple dataframes in one plot.

```
ggplot(data2_CY, aes(x = Date, y = AVERAGETOTALCOST)) + geom_point(color = 'blue') + geom_point(data = data2_CN, color = 'red') + 
  geom_point(data = data2_LY, color = 'cyan') + geom_point(data = data2_LN, color = 'magenta') + 
  labs(title = "Trends Over Time", x = "Time", y = "Average Total Cost") + scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2019-07-01"), by = "6 months"), date_labels = "%b\n%Y") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('C&Y' = 'blue', 'C&N' = 'red', 'L&Y' = 'cyan', 'L&N' = 'magenta'))
```

The code above returns a singular plot with multiple points in the correct colors. However, the `scale_color_manual()` portion of the code does not return a legend. I am trying to display the legend to the right of the graph.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're less likely to get much help when we know nothing about the data. Can you provide sufficient sample data (for all frames used) to demonstrate your question?

Answer (score 0):

The scale_color_manual() must connect to a specific data. My advice to you is to merge all these data and plot them using one dataframe

Comment: If I merge the data, how can I maintain the color coding of the separate dataframes?

Comment: You can create a set of colours separately. 
The plot will be coloured by one variable, after the dataframes will be merged.

This book may help you
https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-colour.html

Comment: I'm not sure this is easily achieveable as my dataframes all have the same types of variables but are separated based on a condition. For example, each dataframe has Average Total Cost but are showing results for those that have C and Y, C and N, L and Y, and L and N. I believe I could merge the data and create new columns, but I was thinking there was a better way.

Comment: For such cases you can use the join() of tidyverse, which keeps all data and merges datasets by a chosen column. 
If it is too complicated, you can simply do the basic plot() + points()